# Get index of value in JSON array in MYSQL?

Tags: java, mysql, json

Is there a way to search by index of a value in JSON array. For instance is there a way way to do something like...

```
Select * FROM table WHERE myJSONArr.indexOf("s") = 3 or 4
```

such that it will return all rows where the index of "s" in a JSON column "myJSONArr" is 3 or 4?

Comment: If you provide some more details, you will probably get more help.  Some example json and expected results.

Comment: What are you putting JSON document inside a SQL database, it defeat the features of the database (index and queries) and doesn't save space. if you need more flexibility maybe you should be considering a NoSQL database like MongoDB.

Comment: @NyamiouTheGaleanthrope MySQL has a json data type and functions to support it, I don't see any issue using JSON in MySQL.  Especially if they are needing a hybrid relational/non relational solution.

Comment: I was looking through some of the options. I see that MYSQL offers ways to get the size of a JSONArray as well as other features but i don't see anything for the index of an element.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you !

```
CREATE TABLE test_json_table (
id integer ,
tags json DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

insert into test_json_table VALUES (1, '["JavaScript", "ES2015", "JSON"]');
insert into test_json_table VALUES (2, '["JavaScript", "Python", "ES2015", "JSON"]');


select v1.*
from (select cast(tags as char) as tags_str from test_json_table) as v1
where POSITION("[" IN v1.tags_str) IN (1,2) ;
```